# How to transfer the display visuals of a component to a temporary canvas in Harmony OS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

In my project, I want to store the currently displayed component in a temporary canvas which I can later reuse. How can I achieve this in Harmony OS?

Answer (score 0):

As confirmed by the team, HarmonyOS does not currently support to achieve this. But there are plans to support it in the future. Please stay tuned on HarmonyOS official websites.